# jQuery check and get attribute of a child element

Tags: jquery

If a user places HTML in a `textarea` field, how can I check if text inserted is an `<object>` tag?

If true, I want to assign the `src` attribute of the `<object`> to a variable.

What the most efficient way to do this?

```
<div id="embed">
    <textarea>
        <object src="..."></object>
    </textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var $obj = $($("#embed textarea").text());
var src = $obj.is("object") ? $obj.attr("src") : null;
```

fixed it

Comment: [`is()` returns a boolean](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/AbM4L/), so you can not chain those methods like that.

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
var textarea = $('#embed textarea'),
    textareaValue = textarea.val(),
    textareaValueDom = $(textareaValue);

if (textareaValueDom.is('object')) {
    var src = textareaValueDom.attr('src');
    console.log(src); // http://example.com
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/MLWK2/).

Comment: Thanks, your answer is similar to the one accepted, but since i asked about efficiency, Ivanov code wins. it's about 15% faster http://jsperf.com/is-selector1.

Comment: @alex OK, but I think you'd be hard pressed to find a situation where you needed this code to be as efficient as possible. If you *really* wanted efficiency, you'd drop jQuery, but of course there is only a few cases where requiring JavaScript to run that fast is necessary.